# Como esconder Divs apartir do evento onClick no input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, bootstrap-4, javascript-eventos

esou com uma dúvida daquelas. Estou refazendo uma páginade um  site médico onde tem  um glosario de busca doenças pela letra index,A,B,C,D,E............

Na pagina, havia um espaço para  os botoes de busca,  estou apanhando para fazer o evendo, exemplo cliquei no botão A, tenho que esconder as DIVS, b,c,d,e....etc

se clicar em S tem que esconder as divs, a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j ....  e somente ficar a S.  Como consigo fazer isso em Jquery ou javascript, to tentando mas acaba escondendo a que deve ficar a mostra.

```
 <input type='submit' class="button" onclick="showPage('#A')" value="A"/>
                                <input type='submit' class="button" onclick="showPage('#B')"value="B"/>
                                <input type='submit' class="button" value="C"/>
                                <input type='submit' class="button" value="D"/>
                                <input type='submit' class="button" value="E"/>
                                <input type='submit' class="button" value="F"/>
                                <input type='submit' class="button" value="G"/>
                                <input type='submit' class="button" value="H"/>
                                <input type='submit' class="button" value="I"/>
                                <input type='submit' class="button" value="J"/>
                                <input type='submit' class="button" value="K"/>
                                <input type='submit' class="button" value="L"/>
                                <input type='submit' class="button" value="M"/>
                                <input type='submit' class="button" value="N"/>
                                <input type='submit' class="button" value="O"/>
                                <input type='submit' class="button" value="P"/>
                                <input type='submit' class="button" value="Q"/>
                                <input type='submit' class="button" value="R"/>
                                <input type='submit' class="button" value="S"/>
                                <input type='submit' class="button" value="T"/>
                                <input type='submit' class="button" value="U"/>
                                <input type='submit' class="button" value="V"/>
                                <input type='submit' class="button" value="X"/>
                                <input type='submit' class="button" value="Y"/>
                                <input type='submit' class="button" value="Z"/>
```

Comment: Cara o primeiro passo é trocar o `type='submit'` pot `type='button'` no Input. Faz isso e testa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".button").click(function(){
         var inputValue = $(this).val();
         if(inputValue){
            //mostra a div com classe correspondente ao Value do input clicado
            $("." + inputValue).show();
            //Esconde as divs class .box e que não tem a classe correspondente ao value do input
            $(".box").not("." + inputValue).hide();
            
         }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <div> 
        <input type='submit' class="button" value="A"/>
        <input type='submit' class="button" value="B"/>
        <input type='submit' class="button" value="C"/>
        <input type='submit' class="button" value="D"/>
    </div>
    
    <div class="A box">
        Div AAAA
    </div>
    
    <div class="B box">
        Div BBBB
    </div>
    
    <div class="C box">
        Div CCCC
    </div>
    
    <div class="D box">
        Div DDDD
    </div>
```

Comment: Leo bom dia teria como fazer essa funcão do jquery para buscar o ID, envés do nome.

Comment: @PedroHenriqueSilvadeDeus, na sua pergunta não tem ID. Edite a pergunta colocando o código adequado

Answer (score 0):

Acabei alterando o codigo porque vi que necessitava tratar mais algumas condições.

```js
function showPage(num) 
        {
            if(num.match('A'))
            {
                                
                document.getElementById('A').style.display="block";
                if($('#B').css('display') == 'none')
                {   
                    //alert("hiider");
                    document.getElementById('B').style.display="block"
                }       
                else if($('#B').is(':visible'))
                {
                       // alert("hiddsr");
                    document.getElementById('B').style.display="none"
                }   
                if($('#C').css('display') == 'none')
                {   
                    //alert("hiider");
                    document.getElementById('C').style.display="block"
                }       
                else if($('#C').is(':visible'))
                {
                       // alert("hiddsr");
                    document.getElementById('C').style.display="none"
                }   
               
            }
```

Agora está funcionando do jeito que me requisitaram,Obrigado Pela Ajuda